# HashMap Searching For A Specific Value in Multiple Keys

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm checking to see if a key in my HashMap exists, if it does, I also want to check to see if any other keys have a value with the same name as that of the original key I checked for or not.

For example I have this.

```
System.out.println("What course do you want to search?");
    String searchcourse = input.nextLine();
boolean coursefound = false;

if(hashmap.containsKey(searchcourse) == true){
    coursefound = true;
        }
```

This checks to see if the key exists in my hashmap, but now I need to check every single key's values for a specific value, in this case the string searchcourse.

Usually I would use a basic for loop to iterate through something like this, but it doesn't work with HashMaps. My values are also stored in a String ArrayList, if that helps.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue(java.lang.Object) like that?

Comment: It says that it returns true, if any keys share the same value, I also want to print out which specific keys have that value in them.

Comment: Real quick comment - sorry if it isn't super helpful, but you can simply write `coursefound = hashmap.containsKey(searchcourse)` and get rid of the if statement.

Comment: `basic for loop to iterate through something like this, but it doesn't work with HashMaps.` Um, what?  You can use for loops to iterate over hashmaps just fine.  More specifically the keyset, valueset or entryset.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look at each entry in the HashMap. This loop should check the contents of the ArrayList for your `searchcourse` and print out the key that contained the value.

```
for (Map.Entry<String,ArrayList> entries : hashmap.entrySet()) {
    if (entries.getValue().contains(searchcourse)) {
        System.out.println(entries.getKey() + " contains " + searchcourse);
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant javadocs:

[Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html)

[HashMap `entrySet` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29)

[ArrayList `contains` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: I believe that his values are Lists of Strings, so this won't work.  But requires some clarification by OP.

Comment: The values for the keys are saved in an ArrayList which is filled with strings.

Comment: So, when I go `map.get(searchcourse)`, would I get back a String or an ArrayList?  Just want to be clear.

Comment: I need to know which keys have that value, so containsValue(searchcourse); would give me true/false, but it wouldn't let me know which keys had those values. Correct?

Comment: And the keys you want returned only need to have the searched course in their ArrayList somewhere, correct?

Comment: Updated for these clarifications

Answer (score 0):

You can have a bi-directional map.  E.g. you can have a `Map<Value, Set<Key>>` or [MultiMap](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) for the values to keys or you can use a bi-directional map which is planned to be added to Guava.

Comment: "Planned to be added"?  `BiMap` is several years old.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Good point, a one-to-one bidirectional map is available now.  a one-to-many bidirectional map is planned AFAIK.

Comment: `ImmutableSetMultimap` already provides an `inverse()` method.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, the values in your Map are `List<String>`.  That is, your Map is declares as `Map<String, List<String>>`.  If so:

```
for (List<String> listOfStrings : myMap.values()) [
  if (listOfStrings .contains(searchcourse) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

If the values are just Strings, i.e. the Map is a `Map<String, String>`, then @Matt has the simple answer.

Comment: `values()` only returns the values. This is not very useful since OP wants the keys that contained the `searchcourse` value. How are you tracking the key in this case?

Comment: He _also_ wants to look at the values.  Looks like you finally sorted it out in your answer...